# Is there a way to make external interrupts active with rising edges in an 8051 microprocessor?

Tags: assembly, 8051

I know the 8051 can handle interrupts both as level triggered and edge triggered. However in order for them to work the pin must be constantly at a high and transition to a low. What can I do if the device connceted to the pin is constantly at a low and i want the ISR to trigger when it goes to high? Is a NOT gate my only option? Or can I bypass the problem with software?

Comment: Inverter is the way to go, yeah.   There are some 8051 packages that have extra stuff that supports rising edge interrupts, IIRC.  But the 8051 proper doesn't support it.

Comment: If the device pulses the interrupt line when triggering an interrupt then it has the opposite edge on the other end of the pulse. The pulse needs to be long enough (one cycle on a real 8051) but that's true regardless. It doesn't matter whether it's normally held high or low by the device, the interrupt line just needs to go from at least 1 cycle of high to at least 1 cycle of low to be recognized as an edge-triggered interrupt. If the device changes the level from low to high when triggering interrupt and then keeps it high until the interrupt is cleared then you'll need the inverter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the working of hardware interrupt using software.
Not gate is the only option unless you want to switch to another controller which may support active high interrupt.